# Zend_db & Zend_paginator - Not having a fun time

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-paginator

I am having a serious problem converting my 'select' statement into something that will work with the zend paginator... could someone have a crack at it, as I am having no luck...

Here is my query:

```
$query = "SELECT
            user_id, name, gender, city, province, country, image_id, one_liner, self_description, reputation
          FROM
            users
          WHERE
          (
            (69.1 * (latitude - " . $user->latitude . ")) * 
            (69.1 * (latitude - " . $user->latitude . "))
          ) + ( 
            (69.1 * (longitude - " . $user->longitude . ") * COS(" . $user->latitude . " / 57.3)) * 
            (69.1 * (longitude - " . $user->longitude . ") * COS(" . $user->latitude . " / 57.3))
          ) < " . pow($radius, 2) . " 
          ORDER BY 
          (
                (69.1 * (latitude - " . $user->latitude . ")) * 
            (69.1 * (latitude - " . $user->latitude . "))
          ) + ( 
            (69.1 * (longitude - " . $user->longitude . ") * COS(" . $user->latitude . " / 57.3)) * 
            (69.1 * (longitude - " . $user->longitude . ") * COS(" . $user->latitude . " / 57.3))
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
        $select = $db->select();
        $select->from(
            array('users'),
                array(
                        'user_id', 
                        'name', 
                        'gender', 
                        'city', 
                        'province', 
                        'country', 
                        'image_id', 
                        'one_liner', 
                        'self_description', 
                        'reputation'
                    )
        );
        $select->where("(69.1 * (latitude - " . $user->latitude . ")) * (69.1 * (latitude - " . $user->latitude . "))) + ((69.1 * (longitude - " . $user->longitude . ") * COS(" . $user->latitude . " / 57.3)) * (69.1 * (longitude - " . $user->longitude . ") * COS(" . $user->latitude . " / 57.3))) < " . pow($radius, 2));
        $select->order("(69.1 * (latitude - " . $user->latitude . ")) * (69.1 * (latitude - " . $user->latitude . "))) + ((69.1 * (longitude - " . $user->longitude . ") * COS(" . $user->latitude . " / 57.3)) * (69.1 * (longitude - " . $user->longitude . ") * COS(" . $user->latitude . " / 57.3))) ASC");
```

Comment: Can you describe the errors or inconsistencies you are experiencing? What, specifically, isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have "<" in your order by clause?

Comment: removed it, still having probs though

Comment: this Answer should have been a comment... ?

Answer (score 1):

What does this have to do with Zend_Paginator? Ah, do you have the query and you don't know how to make a paginator with it, or is the paginator not working with this query?

The only thing I can see is you're missing an opening parenthesis in both the `where()` and `order()` clause:

```
$select->where("((69.1 * [...] ");
$select->order("((69.1 * [...] ");
                 ^
```

So maybe Zend_Paginator isn't working because the SQL query has errors?

And of course I have to ask: are those variables you're interpolating safe, or should you really be using `$db->quote($user->latitude, Zend_Db::FLOAT_TYPE)`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using MVC-pattern, won't this work?

in your bootstrap:

```
Zend_View_Helper_PaginationControl::setDefaultViewPartial('pagination.phtml');
```

in your controller:

```
$page = Zend_Paginator::factory($select);
$page->setCurrentPageNumber($this->_getParam('page', 1));
$page->setItemCountPerPage($this->_getParam('par', 20));
$this->view->results= $page;
```

in your view:

```
<?php foreach($this->results as $result) : ?>
    <!-- print some $result stuff here -->
<?php endforeach;?>
<?= $this->results ?>
```

then place a pagination.phtml example that you can find on zend manual
-Lo